# How to use AreYouSure correctly?

Tags: jquery, forms, jsp, warnings, onbeforeunload

**Update**

I'm trying to warn user before leaving web page with unsaved changes. I saw that it should be easy with the jquery plugin [AreYouSure.js](https://plugins.jquery.com/are-you-sure/)

But, as its not working for me yet, I'd like to know what I've done wrong:

```js
$(function() {
  $('#SummaryTableForm').areYouSure({
    message: 'It looks like you have been editing something. ' +
      'If you leave before saving, your changes will be lost.'
  });
});

function RemoveTableRowfunctionOfSummary(e) {
  $(e).parent().parent().remove();

}
```

```html
<spring:url value="/resources/scripts/SummaryTableScript.js" var="SummaryTableScript" />
<script src="${SummaryTableScript}"></script>
<spring:url value="/resources/scripts/jquery.are-you-sure.js" var="AYS" />
<script src="${AYS}"></script>
<spring:url value="/resources/scripts/ays-beforeunload-shim.js" var="AYSbeforeunload" />
<script src="${AYSbeforeunload}"></script>
<form id="SummaryTableForm" name="SummaryTableForm" method="post" action="">
  <h1>
    <label id="SummaryTableHeadLineLabel">Summary</label>
  </h1>
  <div id="SumHeaderButton">

    <input type="submit" id="SumSaveBtn" value='Save'></input>
    <input type="button" id="SumCancelBtn" value='Cancel'></input>
  </div>
  <div id="SumActionButtons">
    <input type="button" id="SumDeleteBtn" value='Delete' />
    <input type="button" id="SumAddBtn" value='Add'></input>
  </div>
  <div id="SumTableDiv">
    <table id="SumTable">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <td><label id="SummaryTableSelect">Select</label></td>
          <td><label id="SummaryTableActvate">Activate</label></td>
          <td><label id="SummaryTableId">ID</label></td>
          <td><label id="SummaryTableEdit">Edit</label></td>
          <td><label id="SummaryTableDelete">Delete</label></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <select id="SummaryTableSelectAll" onchange="changeSelectAll()">
              <option value="-1"></option>
              <option value="yes">Yes</option>
              <option value="no">No</option>
            </select>
          </td>
          <td>
            <select id="SummaryTableSelectActivate" onchange="changeActivation()">
              <option value="-1"></option>
              <option value="yes">Yes</option>
              <option value="no">No</option>
            </select>
          </td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody id="sumTbody">
        <tr>
          <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
          <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td><input type="button" id="SumDeleteBtn" value='Edit' /></td>
          <td><input type="button" id="SumDeleteBtn" value='Delete' onclick="RemoveTableRowfunctionOfSummary(this)" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
          <td><input type="checkbox" checked></td>
          <td>2</td>
          <td><input type="button" id="SumDeleteBtn" value='Edit' /></td>
          <td><input type="button" id="SumDeleteBtn" value='Delete' onclick="RemoveTableRowfunctionOfSummary(this)" /></td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
    <nav class="limit-per-page" aria-label="Page Navigation">
      <ul class="pagination">
      </ul>
      <ul class="limit-per-page">
        <li><a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="changeTo10()">10
    </a></li>
        <li><a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="changeTo50()">50
    </a></li>
        <li><a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="changeTo100()">100
    </a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
```

The table is filled with ajax in  (I've inserted some example tbl), there I have delete buttons and checkboxes. I want to warn the user before he can click on an other menue-link or before he can close the page, IF he/she has changed the value of the checkbox or if he has deleted the item.

As I'had read before the Are-you-sure.js should be easily implemented with:

```
$('#SummaryTableForm').areYouSure(
  {
    message: 'It looks like you have been editing something. '
       + 'If you leave before saving, your changes will be lost.'
  }
);
```

But it's not working in my code.

**Additional Code for the dynamic table**

Servlet to load the table

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

    String createTableRows = "";

    List<TableRowModel> tableRowModelList= GetExamnTable();
    int paramIndex = 0;

    for (TableRowModel item : tableRowModelList)
    {
        String checked="";
        if(item.getActive()) {
            checked="checked";
        }
        createTableRows += "<tr id=\"SelectTableRowNumber"+paramIndex+"\" class=\"table-row  found-row\">"
            + "<td>"
            + "<input type=\"checkbox\" id=\"SummaryTableSelect"+paramIndex+"\" class=\"sum-table-select\"/>"
            + "</td>"
            + "<td>"
            + "<input type=\"checkbox\" name=\"SummaryTableActvateCheckbox\" id=\"SummaryTableActvate"+paramIndex+"\" "+checked+"  class=\"sum-table-activate\"  onchange=\"setChangedFlag()\"/>"
            + "</td>"
            + "<td class=\"sum-table-id\">"
            + "<label id=\"SummaryTableId"+paramIndex+"\" >"+item.getId()+"</label>"
            + "</td>"
            + "<td>"
            + "<input type=\"button\" value=\""+Utilities.getGeneralResourceMessages("button.Edit")+"\" onclick=\"EditTableRowfunction(this)\""
            + "</td>"
            + "<td>"
            + "<input type=\"button\" name=\"SummaryTableDeleteRow\" value=\""+Utilities.getGeneralResourceMessages("button.Delete")+"\" onclick=\"RemoveTableRowfunctionOfSummary(this)\""
            + "</td></tr>";

        paramIndex++;
    }

    out.print("{");
    out.print("'summaryTable':'" + createTableRows + "'");
    out.print("}");
}
```

Ajax to load the table:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 $("#SummaryTableSelectAll").val("-1");
 $("#SummaryTableSelectActivate").val("-1");
//On Page-Ready load Datatable
$(function() {
    $("#SumTable tbody > tr").remove();
    var url = "Summary";
    var form = $('#SummaryTableForm')[0];
    var data = new FormData(form);
    $.ajax({
            type : "POST",
            url : url,
            data : data,
            processData: false,
            success : function(msg) {
                var objJSON = eval("(function(){return " + msg+ ";})()");
                $("#SumTable  tbody").append(objJSON.summaryTable);
                limitPerPage=3;
                startingPage=1;
                nextPageBlock = blockLimit;
                setPagination(limitPerPage);
                }
    });
});
});
```

If I check or uncheck the checkbox with a `name`-attribute and than move to a different page, I'll not receive the Pop-Up.

**Solution Summary**

To receive the popup, once inputs have to have a `name`-Attribute.
If there is some dynamically created code AYS has to rescann the form: `$('#SummaryTableForm').trigger('rescan.areYouSure');`
If buttons are clicked and the event should trigger the AYS-popup. Then, on button click, one has to add the `class`-attr `dirty` to the form.
`$('#SummaryTableForm').attr("class","dirty");`

Comment: Could you provide a link to the plugin website?

Comment: Sure: https://plugins.jquery.com/are-you-sure/

Comment: does your browser  console has any error ?

Comment: No, if it did I'd try to solve that first before posting, but msgs answers solved most of my problems

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the plugin to work you have to give `name` attributes to the form controls, since it's how it [keeps track of changes](https://github.com/codedance/jquery.AreYouSure/blob/60f199ce6354f9eb8b196575a59610a3c3cebd36/jquery.are-you-sure.js#L32).

Since form fields are collected at `areYouSure` initialization you'll have to manually trigger a rescan of the form after adding new rows as part of your `success` callback:

```
$('#SummaryTableForm').trigger('rescan.areYouSure');
```

Comment: Thx, that helped me a part of the way. I added the name-attribute in the form and the input fields. And if I hard code the fields, than I'm indeed receiving the AYS Pop-Up. BUT, I'm creating the Table dynamically. And even if I add the name-Attibutes. It's nopt popping up. I'll add my code for the dynamic table in a moment.

Comment: thx that worked perfectly for the checkboxes. Now I only have the problem that I'ts not triggerd if I remove the rows with the button click event. After removing the rows I'd like for the event to trigger if I have not saved the changes yet. Is that possible with AYS?

Comment: @Jane_Doe Sorry, I don't follow. What event? The `rescan` or warn the user if the row has changes? I don't think so, but you can tell AYS to mark your fields as dirty. Maybe you can check if the row has changes prior to removing.

Comment: I want to remove the rows if I click on the button 'remove' and I want to change the values after clicking on edit (The row contains a limited ammount of details, after clicking 'edit' a modal wll pop up and the user may change some details, they are not visible in the table). How can I set the status manualy to dirty? I'd just ad that with the rescan in the RemoveTableRowfunctionOfSummary(e){}- functon

Comment: @Jane_Doe If the modal contains another form, you could initialize a new AYS instance , set `addRemoveFieldsMarksDirty: true` in the plugin options and check if the form `hasClass('dirty')` before closing the modal.

Comment: The edit form will not be that problem. My problem is with the delete/remove button. the user should be able to remove the rows but after removing he should save the removal before its permanent. I don't want to change the removal in the database every time the user removes a row. Therefore I'd like the popup to tell me that I did something that I have not yet changed after clicking on the delete-button.

Comment: @Jane_Doe Oh, I think I get it... you are calling `remove()` but you don't actually remove the item from the db until the user hits 'Save'. If you trigger a rescan the field will be gone from the fields tracked by AYS. I don't know how to circumvent that. Maybe hiding the row instead of removing and adding a hidden field that indicates that the row is to be removed.

Comment: Exactly. But thx to you I found my solution. After removing the button I have to add the class 'dirty' to my form: `$('#SummaryTableForm').attr("class","dirty");` that works.